# automake-1.4 missing when trying to install mecab

Tags: python, homebrew, automake, mecab

I have been trying to install mecab-ipadic-NEologd (following [this](https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd) and now being at step 2)
when running `./bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n` I came across messages:

```
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Configure custom system dictionary on /Users/mypc/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build/mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801-neologd-20200910
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /opt/homebrew/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for working aclocal-1.4... missing
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake-1.4... missing
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for working makeinfo... missing
```

so I installed automake through brew and added the path to bashrc.
`which automake` will find automake, but trying to install mecab-ipadic-NEologd again, will lead to the same message. Plus at the end it says

```
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Get results of tokenize test
[test-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Start..
[test-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Replace timestamp from 'git clone' date to 'git commit' date
[test-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Get buzz phrases
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 24483    0 24483    0     0  44949      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 45088
[test-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Get difference between default system dictionary and mecab-ipadic-NEologd
[test-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Something wrong. You shouldn't install mecab-ipadic-NEologd yet.
```

So I assume I shouldn't ignore the error here. :D

---

I am using:
Mac OS Ventura 13.3 M1 Chip
pyenv with Python 3.11.1

Comment: I suspect you need to remove the partially built files, but I'm not sure. Note that Neologd has not been updated in years (despite what the README says), I would strongly recommend against using it.